# Let $G$ be a group and let $a, b$ be elements of $G$, show that $|ab|=l.c.m (|a|,|b|)$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and let $a, b$ be elements of $G$ such that:

i) $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle={\{1}\}$

ii) $ab=ba$

II) $|a|=m, |b|=n$

Show that $|ab|=l.c.m (|a|,|b|)$

Idea: Note that $a^m=1,\; b^n=1,$ let's do $k=l.c.m (|a|,|b|)$ (least common multiple), $|ab|=w,$ hence $(ab)^k=a^kb^k=1,$ then $k$ divides $w$, How can I prove that $ w $ divides $ k $? Thanks so much for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $1=(ab)^w=a^wb^w$ so $\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert\mid w$, hence $lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)\mid w$. Also, $(ab)^{lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)}=a^{lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)}b^{lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)}=(a^{\lvert a\rvert})^{\frac{lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)}{\lvert a\rvert}}(b^{\lvert b\rvert})^{\frac{lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)}{\lvert b\rvert}}=1$, so $w\mid lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)$. Thus $w=lcm(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)$.